# Yii2 How to correctly login user on frontend by using data from API

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I'm use yii2 advanced tamplate, and I'm try understand how to correctly login user, on frontend part of application, using only some data, who's describe user entity, requested from API, without using database.

At first I'm tell about what is done.

Configuration in `frontend\config\main` mostly is native, I'm don't touch it, change only

`'components' => ['user' => 'identityClass => frontend\models\User']`.

I'm think that, if I haven't database, user data must be contain in session.

I'm have `User` model in `frontend\models`. In `User` model realized two methods for get data of current user from API. They are `findIdentityByAccessToken` and `getId`.

```
namespace frontend\models;


use yii\base\Model;
use yii\httpclient\Exception;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use yii\httpclient\Client;

class User extends Model implements IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        // TODO: Implement findIdentity() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        $client = new Client(['baseUrl' => 'http://api.somesite.com/api/v1']);

        try {
            $user = $client->get('user', [], ['Authorization' => "Bearer $token"])->send();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        $model = new self();

        $model->load(json_decode($user->content, true), '');

        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getAuthKey() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        // TODO: Implement validateAuthKey() method.
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['email', 'username', 'id'], 'safe'],
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            [['username'], 'string'],
            [['email'], 'email']
        ];
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

Next, from site controller, action login, I'm send response to API for get authenticate token and life time of token. After that use `Yii::$app->user->loginByAccessToken($token, $type)` for log in user. But nothing happens.

```
    /**
     * Logs in a user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();

        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && ! $model->login()->hasErrors()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            $model->password = '';

            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

`LoginForm` model

```
namespace frontend\models;


use yii\base\Model;
use yii\httpclient\Client;
use yii\httpclient\Exception;
use Yii;

class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'password'], 'safe']
        ];
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $client = new Client(['baseUrl' => 'http://api.somesite.com/api/v1']);

        try {
            $auth = $client->post('user/auth', ['username' => $this->username, 'password' => $this->password])->send();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        $data = json_decode($auth->content);

        if ($auth->isOk) {
            return Yii::$app->user->loginByAccessToken($data->token);
        } else {
            foreach ($data as $error) {
                $this->addError($error->field, $error->message);
            }
            $this->password = '';

            return $this;
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, I'm understand what `Yii::$app->user->loginByAccessToken` take source from `yii2\web\User` method `loginByAccessToken`. When inspect this method and `var_dump($identity)`, I'm expected to see, loaded `User` model by data requested from API. Because method `loginByAccessToken` in `frontent\models\User` responce this user data, load in model and return. But I see nothing, `$identity` contain empty model.

At second what I don't understand how it work.

Why if my `frontent\models\User loginByAccessToken` return loaded model then in `yii2\web\User loginByAccessToken` variable `$identity` show me empty model?

Why if I'm realized in `frontent\models\User` method `findIdentity` and return array with
user data, login work, but where this method called in `yii2\web\User` if I'm don't use them?

Please explane me what I must do first, second and third step, what I do wrong or how realize it right?
 Because my ideas are empty. Thanks for any help.

Comment: if you have not a db  how you can store valid  credential for matching the value inputed  by user????  .. a login (normally) provide values to compare with valid credential stored somewhere ..

Comment: Is that `fronten**t**` in `'components' => ['user' => 'identityClass => frontent\models\User'].` just typo in your question or is that a typo in your config?

Comment: @scaisEdge username and password compare when I'm send them on API. Data about user stored in database on API side. This is visible in login() method LoginForm model.

Comment: @MichalHynčica sorry, this is mistake in my question